# Equivalent Formulation of Least Squares Method in Terms of Entropy

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, error-analysis, statistics, information

I have learned that people in the field of machine learning and statistics often use the least squares method.
Is there any alternative formulation of the least squares method using entropy? (It might be better to ask if it is related to entropy in physics or information theory.)

Sorry for the very vague question, but when I saw it I got a naive idea that it is kind of similar to what I learned about entropy in some of the Physics courses I took at University.

Comment: They mean Shannon entropy rather than the entropy used in physics (although sometimes the two overalap), see, e.g., [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/656263/247642). I think the question is more suitable for cross-validated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one important sense in which the answer is yes. Least squares is equivalent to maximum likelihood estimation for IID (and hence [equal-variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoscedasticity)) zero-mean Gaussian errors. Their being Gaussian maximizes continuous Shannon entropy for their mean and variance.